# Why does my debugg system on the webbrowser tell me (drawImage is not a function)?

Tags: javascript, function, drawimage, javascript-debugger

I am making a JavaScript program while I tried to draw an image. I just searched on Google how to do it and multiply sources told me the same:

```
ctx.drawImage(images[0],100,100);
```

I tried to do this so, I made an array and putted in a image in their and then a src and tried to draw the image but my Firefox debugger tells me "drawImage is not a function".

This is my code:

```
var images = new Array();
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
images[0] = new Image();
images[0].src=("img/w1.png");
ctx.drawImage(images[0],100,100);
```

BTW this works on the program :

```
ctx[1].fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx[1].fillRect(x[0], y[0], 50, 50);
```

Comment: where do you have `ctx` set?

Comment: Thank you. You helped me out dident thought about that i had `ctx[0] = canvas.getContext('2d');`

Comment: So, `ctx` is an array, not actually the drawing context.

Comment: ctx was an array, i made it into just var ctx.

`var ctx;
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(images[0],100,100);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you define your ctx right it should work.

```
var images = new Array();
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
images[0] = new Image();
images[0].src=("img/w1.png");
ctx.drawImage(images[0],100,100);
```